# XAudio2 filter radian frequency

Tags: filter, signal-processing, frequency, xaudio2

In the documentation for the [XAudio2 filter parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.xaudio2.xaudio2_filter_parameters%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it mentions

> Filter radian frequency calculated as (2 * sin(pi * (desired filter cutoff frequency) / sampleRate))

Can someone explain to me where that formula comes from? Because the only source of frequency conversion that would make sense to me would come from sin(f * t) and cosine(f * t) vs sin(2*pi*f * t) and cosine(2*pi*f * t) where f is a "frequency" and t is time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(2 * sin(pi * (desired filter cutoff frequency) / sampleRate))
```

This value will go monotonically from 0 to 2.0 as the filter cut-off frequency goes from DC to half the sample rate.

Digital filters scale relative to the sample rate, and your other offered options don't.

Comment: Ok but I'm still puzzled about why "filter radian frequency" is DEFINED by that formula. It feels like the formula is just randomly chosen. Why that formula and not another?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done filter math. It's kind of gnarly, but here's a basic interpretation: 
The part that's a little confusing is the Sin no? I'm a little confused by it too, but I bet it's to keep the output of the conversion in the desired range. Looks like Microsoft's filter can only take up 8000hz. Forgive me if this way off base, I can't visualize what a sine function would do to the results at the moment.

2 * sin(pi * (desired filter cutoff frequency) / WHOLE THING

PARTS

2 * sin                         //// The 2*pi*f part you're used to.

(pi *
(

desired filter cutoff frequency)       //// This in hertz will become radian freqs

/ sampleRate                               //// Sets up the whole equation for 1 sample